# not working drop down menu properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

Right now I am doing dropdown menu with this following source plugins these all plugins are used for  one image sliding now I can’t remove it this easing-1.3.pack.js , easing-compatibility.1.2.pack.js, coda-slider.1.1.1.pack.js , and  as per my situation this dropdown is not working properly and also showing hiding very low time when I mouse over showing link pull down and up continually.

Comment: What does "not working properly" mean?

Comment: when I mouse over showing submenu content pull down and up continually.

Comment: give me a link to checkout this

Comment: okay i will give in jsfiddle \

Comment: please check the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/kcNXJ/

Comment: try this way, check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kcNXJ/16/)

Comment: thank you very much it's very useful for me and also you made great with out modifying my css.

Comment: @PreethiJain  I think you need to pass in some arguments for .stop().. try this out http://jsfiddle.net/cBzeu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be able to at least point you in the correct direction...

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutmatt/kcNXJ/11/

Answer (score 0):

everything is working properly
try to use show() and hide() functions instead of slide and see what happeds
problem is when you slide this take some time and some time takes slide up after slide down :]
if you enter and leave area few times - slideup and down is executed few times to